# Are records of certificate actions available?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa

Are there any online records that may indicate why a specific DPE may have lost qualifications recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to privacy concerns, certificate actions are not made publicly available without a formal request, and have to be made via an acceptable means.

The FAA has a document titled [Information Provided by PRIA, FOIA, and the Privacy Act](http://www.faa.gov/pilots/lic_cert/pria/guidance/) which goes into details about how information can be requested and what they will provide:

- PRIA is basically a request made by a hiring air carrier, so you wouldn't be able to do that.
- FOIA is the Freedom of Information Act, and the above document states:

> Through FOIA, ANY enforcement action, whether still open or fully
>   adjudicated and closed, can be reported.

- The Privacy Act allows you to request your own records, or a third party *company* may request records, so neither of these would apply in your case either.

Comment: Also worth reading: [FAA Order 1270.1](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/1270.1.pdf) which is the FAA's internal process for dealing with FOIA requests. This order details what an "acceptable" request is, and how you should go about making it.

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't answer your questions directly, but you can begin by looking through the [FAA's Quarterly Enforcement Reports](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/operations/agc300/reports/Quarters/).

*(You may be able to find more detailed information somewhere else on that same site. I'm not sure.)*

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but interesting nonetheless, thanks!